# Can I change just the cell reference letter rather than all of that letter within a formula for the entire column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, replace

I have made an error when copying formulas across multiple columns and need to correct them. The issue is I have multiple breaks in the rows so I can't just drag the formula down for each column.

If I use search and replace to change the letter, it also replaces all other letters within the formula.

Is there a way to just change the cell reference letter?

Example:

`=VLOOKUP(C10,CAT!A:C,3,FALSE)`

If I find and replace C, as I need to change it to D10, I end up with `=VLOOKUP(D10,DAT!A:D,3,FALSE)` but need to end up with `=VLOOKUP(D10,CAT!A:C,3,FALSE)`

Any help would be very much appreciated as it is a very large spreadsheet and I am dreading doing it manually.

Cheers

Comment: use thre steps: Rename your sheet DAT to e.g. XYZ (the formulas will adjust automatically). Then you can do your replace D > C and afterwards re-rename your sheet to DAT.

Comment: Thanks Ike but there are numerous repeated letters within the formulas, this was an example one to keep it simple but even with that one, it would also change A:C

Comment: Then you will have to go with VBA and regular expressions - I think.

Comment: It might help to adjust your settings ( _Options_ -> _Formulas_ -> _R1C1 reference style_ ) before you using _Find & Replace_ ; then you would only have to be concerned about the implications for letters `R` and `C`, and not worry about the other 24

Comment: find and replace with more characters, so it will identify only the parts that you want to change: '(C10' replace with '(D10' you can do multiple find and replaces this way until your formula is correct, you can also just select the column where you want these changes to happen.,